# Raspberry Pi bluetooth connection error: "Connection reset by peer"

Tags: linux, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, raspbian, bluez

Good day. I am trying connect bluetooth loudspeaker to Raspberry Pi (RP). I've successfully connected the bluetooth headset using:

```
sudo bluetoothctl
pair <Headphones' MAC Address>
connect <Headphones' MAC Address>
```

And everything is all right. But when I am trying connect to soundspeaker it is not.

```
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller 00:15:83:15:A3:10 Discovering: yes
[NEW] Device F9:56:48:48:A6:8C 17979 speaker
[bluetooth]# pair F9:56:48:48:A6:8C
Attempting to pair with F9:56:48:48:A6:8C
[CHG] Device F9:56:48:48:A6:8C Connected: yes
[CHG] Device F9:56:48:48:A6:8C Connected: no
[CHG] Device F9:56:48:48:A6:8C Connected: yes
[CHG] Device F9:56:48:48:A6:8C Connected: no
[CHG] Device F9:56:48:48:A6:8C Paired: yes
Pairing successful
[bluetooth]# trust F9:56:48:48:A6:8C
[CHG] Device F9:56:48:48:A6:8C Trusted: yes
Changing F9:56:48:48:A6:8C trust succeeded
[bluetooth]# info F9:56:48:48:A6:8C
Device F9:56:48:48:A6:8C (public)
    Name: 17979 speaker
    Alias: 17979 speaker
    Class: 0x00240418
    Icon: audio-card
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: no
    LegacyPairing: yes
[bluetooth]# connect F9:56:48:48:A6:8C
Attempting to connect to F9:56:48:48:A6:8C
[CHG] Device F9:56:48:48:A6:8C Connected: yes
[CHG] Device F9:56:48:48:A6:8C Connected: no
[CHG] Device F9:56:48:48:A6:8C Connected: yes
[CHG] Device F9:56:48:48:A6:8C Connected: no
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
```

Here is result of **journalctl:** (I think, 2 last lines are important)

```
journalctl -u bluetooth | tail
Feb 27 22:52:58 raspberrypi bluetoothd[318]: F9:56:48:48:A6:8C: error updating services: Connection reset by peer (104)
Feb 27 22:54:57 raspberrypi bluetoothd[318]: F9:56:48:48:A6:8C: error updating services: Connection reset by peer (104)
Feb 27 22:59:16 raspberrypi bluetoothd[318]: Authentication attempt without agent
Feb 27 22:59:16 raspberrypi bluetoothd[318]: Hands-Free Voice gateway rejected 17:09:22:17:0D:31: org.bluez.Error.Rejected
Feb 27 23:00:17 raspberrypi bluetoothd[318]: Authentication attempt without agent
Feb 27 23:00:17 raspberrypi bluetoothd[318]: Hands-Free Voice gateway rejected 17:09:22:17:0D:31: org.bluez.Error.Rejected
Feb 27 23:00:51 raspberrypi bluetoothd[318]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_17_09_22_17_0D_31/fd0: fd(25) ready
Feb 27 23:02:04 raspberrypi bluetoothd[318]: Unable to get io data for Hands-Free Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
Feb 27 23:34:39 raspberrypi bluetoothd[318]: F9:56:48:48:A6:8C: error updating services: Connection reset by peer (104)
Feb 27 23:35:48 raspberrypi bluetoothd[318]: F9:56:48:48:A6:8C: error updating services: Connection reset by peer (104)
```

What have I done wrong ? I'll appreciate any advice.

Comment: Can you try launching bluetoothctl using the following command instead:- "sudo bluetoothctl --agent KeyboardDisplay", then follow the same sequence as you did before and see what happens